# Creating a List from User input {with Unlimited User Input}

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to create a function definition that asks the user to enter a int or float value to be added to an empty list, but continues to ask the user for input until the user types in -1 or so (<0).

This is what I have so far, but all it does is take the user's input and replicates it 5 times [range(5)] in the new list, and doesn't allow the user to enter anymore values....

I'm very stuck even though I feel it should be pretty easy:

```
def main():
    salesList = []
    salesValue = float(input('Please enter total sales in your department: '))
    while salesValue < 0:
        salesValue = float(input('Please enter a value greater than or equal to zero: '))
        if salesValue == -1:
            break
    else:
        for values in range(5):
            salesList.append(salesValue)
    print(salesList)



main()
```

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated, as I am new to programming.

**:::The easy solution:::**

```
    def makeList():
        salesList = []
        while True:
            salesValue = float(input('Please enter total sales in your department: '))
            if salesValue == -1:
                break        
            salesList.append(salesValue)
        return salesList
```

Comment: Yes, that's what you asked it to do. Why do you have that for loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
# here you are saying, for 5 iterations do the following
for values in range(5):
    # append the single float value salesValue to salesList
    # naturally this will happen 5 times
    salesList.append(salesValue)
```

So it makes total sense that you end up with a list containing 
the salesValue five times over.

Think about this:

```
while True: # will loop until a break
    salesValue = float(input('Please enter a value greater than or equal to zero (-1 to end): '))
    if salesValue < 0:
        break
    else:
        salesList.append(salesValue)
```

Comment: the "while true" part doesn't seem to work in the program I am using. I am only familiar with boolean expressions in a while statement.

Comment: @justachillGamer Ooops, sorry, had a typo, it should be True, not true. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code has a mistake. Basically, when the flow finally reaches the `for` statement, the value of `salesValue` does not change, so the program appends the same value 5 times. Try this instead:

```
def main():
    salesList = []
    salesValue = float(input())
    while salesValue < 0:
        salesvalue = float(input())
        if salesValue == -1:
            break
    for values in range (5):
        salesList.append(salesValue)
        salesValue = float(input("yourmessage"))
    print salesList

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
while salesValue > 0:
```

instead of

```
while salesValue < 0:
```

As you have it written now, the user inputs a value greater than 0, which automatically kicks it into the else block. You will be able to remove the

```
if salesValue == -1:
        break
```

as well.